# Is there a way of listing the enable google cloud APIs in a given project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api-python-client

I want to list every enabled API in a given Google Cloud project by using Python or another gcp API...

I can't find the right snippet code for reproducing some method that do that in the docs, the closest thing I reach was the list_services method from the [python API](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/serviceusage/latest/google.cloud.service_usage_v1.services.service_usage.ServiceUsageClient#google_cloud_service_usage_v1_services_service_usage_ServiceUsageClient_list_services) but it is auto generated template code and does not run.

Comment: See my example code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57529149/8016720). I have also written several answers on this topic. Search [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A8016720+enabled+services)

Comment: I ended up doing different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this very good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57526808/how-do-you-enable-gcp-apis-through-the-python-client-library/57529149#57529149) by @JohnHanley as community wiki for the benefit of the community members that might encounter this use case in the future:

Per John:

> Here is an example that I wrote. Note. This code does not process the `nextPageToken` so it only prints the first 50 services. Add code to loop.

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()

project = 'projects/myproject'

service = discovery.build('serviceusage', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
request = service.services().list(parent=project)

response = ''

try:
    response = request.execute()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    exit(1)

# FIX - This code does not process the nextPageToken
# next = response.get('nextPageToken')

services = response.get('services')

for index in range(len(services)):
    item = services[index]

    name = item['config']['name']
    state = item['state']

    print("%-50s %s" % (name, state))
```

> The output of this code looks similar to this:

```
abusiveexperiencereport.googleapis.com             DISABLED
acceleratedmobilepageurl.googleapis.com            DISABLED
accessapproval.googleapis.com                      DISABLED
accesscontextmanager.googleapis.com                DISABLED
actions.googleapis.com                             DISABLED
adexchangebuyer-json.googleapis.com                DISABLED
adexchangebuyer.googleapis.com                     DISABLED
adexchangeseller.googleapis.com                    DISABLED
adexperiencereport.googleapis.com                  DISABLED
admin.googleapis.com                               ENABLED
adsense.googleapis.com                             DISABLED
```

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.

Answer (score 0):

```
from googleapiclient import discovery

project_id = 'my-project-id'

client = discovery.build('serviceusage', 'v1beta1')
response = client.services().list(
                parent=f'projects/{project_id}',
                filter='state:ENABLED'
            ).execute()

[enabled_service.get('config').get('name') for enabled_service in response.get('services')]
```